Powerbi that shows agenda (DAX)
Hi ia am trying to get a automated agenda for reports that have to be due by a frequent moment. For instace a report that has to be done every tuesday or a report that has to be done every 3th working day of the month.The weeklys are working but i am having problems with the monthlys. This is my dax code now:
RapportPlanning = 
VAR WekelijkseDatums =
    GENERATE(
        'DatumTabel',
        FILTER(
            'Data raports',
            'Data raports'[Frequentie] = "Wekelijks" &&
            WEEKDAY('DatumTabel'[Date], 2) = SWITCH('Data raports'[Dag],
                "Maandag", 1,
                "Dinsdag", 2,
                "Woensdag", 3,
                "Donderdag", 4,
                "Vrijdag", 5,
                BLANK() // Voor het geval dat er geen match is
            )
        )
    )

VAR MaandelijkseDatums =
    GENERATE(
        'DatumTabel',
        FILTER(
            'Data raports',
            'Data raports'[Frequentie] = "Maandelijks" &&
            (
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "1ste werkdag" && 
                (DAY('DatumTabel'[Date]) = 1 && 'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag])) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "2de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 2
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "3de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 3
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "4de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 4
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "5de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 5
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "6de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 6
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "7de werkdag" && 
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 7
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "12de werkdag" &&
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 12
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "13de werkdag" &&
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 13
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "14de werkdag" &&
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 14
                )) ||
                ('Data raports'[Dag] = "15de werkdag" &&
                (
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            'DatumTabel',
                            'DatumTabel'[IsWerkdag] = TRUE &&
                            'DatumTabel'[Date] <= EARLIER('DatumTabel'[Date])
                        )
                    ) = 15
                ))
            )
        )
    )

RETURN
    DISTINCT(UNION(WekelijkseDatums, MaandelijkseDatums))

Tables in powerbi:

And the data with reports and frequencys look like this:

Desired result:

Thank you very much
I have tried watching yourtube use chatgpt and asked experts so this is my last resort

"but i am having problems with the monthlys."  Please edit your question to contain a clear description of what your problem is,  and what you've tried so far.

Hi jeff thanks for responding i am getting only 1 entry for every montly rapport but my goal is to get a entry every month on the working day I provided in the data table depending on the frequentcy and wordkdays "Werkdag"
